# Vbs throws syntax error. I can't see why

Tags: vbscript

I get a syntax error but i can't see why.
I'm currently writing some script in vbs and im new to vbs.
Since the behavior of this script confuses me i got the idea that i have done something wrong.
here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Const read =1,overwrite=2,append=8 'constants for parameters of OpenTextFile command

Dim fos,i,ofile,text,month,day,year,hour,minute,day2

Set fos =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'fos.OpenTextFile("path",type)

ofile =fos.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\martin\Desktop\txt\ReminderV1_0\daten\termin1.txt",1)

'read a date from a txt file
day=ofile.readline
month=ofile.readline
year=ofile.readline
hour=ofile.readline
minute=ofile.readline
set ofile=ofile.close

wscript.echo "abcde" 'i never get a messagebox "abcde" and i dont know why

If day eqv "01" then day2="first" 'use of eqv or = seems to be meaningless
ElseIf day="02"  day2="second" 
ElseIf day="03"  day2="third"
Else day2=day & "-th"
End if

msgbox "2"

text="the " & day2 & " of "& month & " " & year & " at "& hour &":"& minute &" o'clock"

msgbox "3"
msgbox text
```

It should read a date and time from a txt-file (name:"termin1") located in the folder and looking like this:

```
01
07
2014
19
20
```

I haven't come very far.
If i run this i get the following Error message:
Sorry for bad translation maybe(i'm german)

```
Line: 23
token/char: 5
Error: Syntaxerror
Code: 800A03EA
Source: Compilationerror in Microsoft VBScript
```

So that would be the "E" of my first Elseif.
But since i looked it up on Youtube and several websites the Syntax is correct.
Also even though i call an echo in line 20 ("abcde") i never get any echo.
My only guess is that i have used any objects wrong or violated any rules i don't know yet because i lack the experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. Single line syntax (`If foo Then bar`) doesn't support `ElseIf`, and even if it did, you'd still have to put the entire statement in a single line. In your case you **must** use block syntax:

   ```
   If condition1 Then
     ...
   ElseIf condition2 Then
     ...
   ElseIf condition3 Then
     ...
   Else
     ...
   End If
   ```
2. `eqv` is not a valid comparison operator in VBScript. Use `=`.
3. [`Day`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyhfe92k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a built-in function, so it shouldn't be used as a variable. The same goes for [`Month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eeeket2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [`Year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhzx965c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [`Hour`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5dx569a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [`Minute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f41h26kz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Use different variable names instead.

To sum up, change this:

```
day=ofile.readline
month=ofile.readline
year=ofile.readline
hour=ofile.readline
minute=ofile.readline
set ofile=ofile.close

wscript.echo "abcde" 'i never get a messagebox "abcde" and i dont know why

If day eqv "01" then day2="first" 'use of eqv or = seems to be meaningless
ElseIf day="02"  day2="second" 
ElseIf day="03"  day2="third"
Else day2=day & "-th"
End if
```

into this:

```
dayRead    = ofile.ReadLine
monthRead  = ofile.ReadLine
yearRead   = ofile.ReadLine
hourRead   = ofile.ReadLine
minuteRead = ofile.ReadLine
ofile.Close

Wscript.Echo "abcde"

If dayRead = "01" Then
  day2 = "first"
ElseIf dayRead = "02" Then
  day2 = "second"
ElseIf dayRead = "03" Then
  day2 = "third"
Else
  day2 = dayRead & "-th"
End If
```

and the error(s) will disappear.

Comment: very very helpful thank you. everything is working right now. so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If day = "01" then day2="first" 'use of eqv or = seems to be meaningless
  ElseIf day="02"  then day2="second" 
  ElseIf day="03" then day2="third"
  Else day2=day & "-th"
 End if
```